# Replace json string inside a list

Tags: python

I would like to remove the 'T' and 'Z' from the updated_date field

I have json data inside a list.

```
import json

jsonlist = [{'data': {'id': 13471293, 'updated_date': '2023-04-27T22:00:11Z'}},{'data': {'id': 423712896, 'kyc_updated_date': '2023-04-27T18:23:11Z'}}]
print(jsonlist )
```

Comment: Use a for loop (`for subdict in jsonlist`) and modify each `subdict['data']['updated_date']` to value you need (modified original `subdict['data']['updated_date']` - probably replacing T with space and stripping Z/last character?). So: `for subdict in jsonlist: subdict['data']['updated_date'] = subdict['data']['updated_date'].rstrip('Z').replace('T', ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to modify updated_date and not kyc_updated_date:

```py
for elt in jsonlist:
    d = elt["data"]
    if "updated_date" in d:
        d["updated_date"] = d["updated_date"].replace("T", "").replace("Z", "")
```

your `jsonlist` will be :

```py
[{'data': {'id': 13471293, 'updated_date': '2023-04-2722:00:11'}},
 {'data': {'id': 423712896, 'kyc_updated_date': '2023-04-27T18:23:11Z'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the date, you might be best parsing it with the `datetime` module. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

jsonlist = [{'data': {'id': 13471293, 'updated_date': '2023-04-27T22:00:11Z'}},{'data': {'id': 423712896, 'kyc_updated_date': '2023-04-27T18:23:11Z'}}]

parsed_date = datetime.strptime(jsonlist[0]["data"]["updated_date"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
# datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 27, 22, 0, 11)
```

This would give you a `datetime` object, which you can format as desired for your use case. For example, if you wanted it back only down to the minute:

```
parsed_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
# '2023-04-27 22:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that an 'updated_date' value is always in the form YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ then you can slice the string (rather than calling replace) as follows:

```
import json

jsonlist = [{'data': {'id': 13471293, 'updated_date': '2023-04-27T22:00:11Z'}},{'data': {'id': 423712896, 'kyc_updated_date': '2023-04-27T18:23:11Z'}}]

K = 'updated_date'
D = 'data'

for e in jsonlist:
    if (data := e.get(D)):
        if (v := data.get(K)):
            data[K] = v[:10] + v[11:-1]

print(json.dumps(jsonlist, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": 13471293,
      "updated_date": "2023-04-2722:00:11"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": 423712896,
      "kyc_updated_date": "2023-04-27T18:23:11Z"
    }
  }
]
```